# Get file name with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the file name that i upload and show it in my `<span>` .
this is my code:

```
var filename = $('#image_file').val();
$('#select_file').html(filename);

<div class="container-input-custom">
   <div class="upload-btn">
      <span id="select_file"></span>
      <label for="file-upload"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input type="file" id="image_file">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some simple example. I hope this will help to you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#image_file").on("change", function() {
     $("#select_file").html(this.value);
  });
});
```

Edit: 
 Only now I realized what the problem is.
So this is the code:

```
$(".upload-btn").one("click", function _handler(event) {
        _handler.oldContext = this;
        var _file = $(this).find("input[type='file']").one("change", function() {
        var oldContext =    $(_handler.oldContext);
            oldContext.find("span#select_file").html(this.value);
        $(this).attr("display", "none"); 
        oldContext.one("click", _handler); 
    });
    _file.attr("display","block").trigger("click");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and this is working jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qpo8dwf9/33/

Edit2: This is working example with two inputs and attach listeners on document ready.

https://jsfiddle.net/qpo8dwf9/38/

Edit3: There is issues under Chrome and Chromium with fakepath. This is the last version. 
https://jsfiddle.net/qpo8dwf9/49/

Comment: ОК. Explain the problem better please.  How exactly you upload the file? What is your back-end? Is this snippet is located into upload form?

Comment: The answer has changed. This is a very non standart solution.

Comment: hmm in the fiddle it wokrs, but when i implement it it starts automatically to open the dialog for file upload and when i do it it doesn show the text :/, can we caht pls

Comment: The answer is edited. There is improvement. We handle case when the user click cancel on upload.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already amde this the answer but if you could it explain a little would be perfect for others and me too :D

Answer (score 0):

This is some example of getting the name of a file uploaded

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){

            var fileName = e.target.files[0].name; //getting the file name 
            var display = $("#select_file"); //where to display
            display.html(fileName);

        });

    });
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code hope this will help you :).

Comment: hmm it seems to work, but i have 2 of them and when i upadte the first it also shows on the second, how to do it seperatly ?

Comment: I 'm not understanding your problem well, please explain much better the problem.

Comment: i have 2 input type file